# Cannot programmatically navigate back anymore in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So basically I have a simple view like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var navStack = NavigationPath()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navStack) {
            NavigationLink {
                Button {
                    dismiss()
                } label: {
                    Text("Pop Back")
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Detail View")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem is:** when I tap on the "Pop back" button in the detail view, I get the following error message:

```
[Scene] Invalid attempt to call -[UIApplication requestSceneSessionDestruction:] from an unsupported device.
```

I don't understand why this error is occuring. It was working perfectly fine before but I keep getting this error. I am using iOS 16 so I'm not sure if there is a bug.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thank you!

**Edit:**

I created a fresh project with nothing but the view I have displayed above. I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/dismiss) of **dismiss** you will find that its An action that dismisses the current presentation. So, if you present a view then this env variable will dismiss it from the parent view otherwise it will show log message which means that there is no view to dismiss. Here is an example of its use

```
private struct SheetContents: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        Button("Done") {
            dismiss()
        }
    }
}

private struct DetailView: View {
    @State private var isSheetPresented = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet") {
            isSheetPresented = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSheetPresented) {
            SheetContents()
        }
    }
}
```

So when I press the Done button from **SheetContents** the presenting view will remove from parent.

[image]

Comment: Is that not what my snippet is doing? The NavigationLink pushes a view with a  the dismiss button. Therefore when I click the button, it should dismiss the page. I get what you’re saying but I don’t really get why mine doesn’t work.

Comment: Wait. Is it because I created the dismiss in the main view? So if I created a separate struct for the detail view and created the dismiss var there, it would work?

Comment: Actually you are pushing a view therefore dismiss() did't work there.